# Interop - Excel to Word copy - Shrink table width to fit Word document page width

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I am copying a cell range from Excel to Word which contains several tables.
I need to have my document set to portrait. The issue is the copied tables width is larger than width of Word document page. So I can only see part of the table, the other part goes out of the Word document, hence can't see it.

Once the Word doc is created I can manually shrink the table width to fit Word documents page width. How can I achieve that in programmatically using Office Interop?

`document.PageSetup.PageWidth = (float)500` didn't work out for me. 
I saw there is a property as `AutoFitBehavior`: `Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow` but not sure how it can be apply to the Word document.

Appreciate any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

As you asked some questions in your question body, I can answer some of them as:

> I need to have my document set to portrait:

You should insert a section break then change the orientation:

```
doc.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Wd.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
doc.Sections.Last.PageSetup.Orientation = orientation;
```

Or set orientation after creating document

```
doc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
```

---

> Once the Word doc is created I can manually shrink the table width to fit Word documents page width. How can I achieve that in programmatically using Office Interop?

You need just to set [`PreferredWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table.preferredwidth.aspx) too 100 percent after setting its type to `wdPreferredWidthPercent`:

```
table.PreferredWidthType = Wd.WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
table.PreferredWidth = 100.0f;
```

---

> I saw there is a property as `AutoFitBehavior`: `Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow` but not sure how it can be apply to the Word document:

You can use `AutoFitBehavior` like this:

```
table.AllowAutoFit = true;
table.AutoFitBehavior(Wd.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow);
```